# ExtJs dependency management using RequireJS, LABjs (or similar)

Tags: extjs, requirejs, extjs3, dependency-management, labjs

I am trying to find examples of how to wrap ExtJs and ExtJs 'modules' up for use with a javascript dependency framework such as RequireJS or LAB.

I am working with a large ExtJs based project and there are many separate module files which are just bulk included everywhere and it is getting a little out of control.

Has anyone used an existing depenency management framework with ExtJs? (I know ExtJs 4 may include something similar, but I am fixed on using ExtJs 3)

Comment: It would be really nice to see a build (using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)) with Ext JS 3.x and RequireJS

Comment: This might help anyone working toward such a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12340092/320399

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own dependency utility (well my boss wrote it as a method for another framework we are building, and I just ported it to ExtJS) as a mixin where you can just define what your dependencies are, and include events for when they are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Using Grunt
https://github.com/mattgoldspink/grunt-sencha-dependencies

Sencha Cmd now does it automatically as well - unfortunately it considers ExtJS4.1 as legacy, let alone 3.