# RequireJS: Is there a way to achieve multiple base URLs?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I want to use a separate domain as a JavaScript framework and it will create a base require config which I can augment from the app.

```
foo.example.com
    main.js
    lib/foo-specific.js
framework.example.com
    framework.js <-- entry point
    lib/jquery.js
    lib/etc...
```

Optimally, I'd like to be able to require 'lib/foo-specific' and/or 'lib/jquery' and have the paths just resolve nicely, but from what I've found, there's no way to do this, unless I use a specific path key/value for every js file in the framework. At the moment, I've got a custom plugin to load the given path with a different base url (e.g. `fw!lib/jquery`), though if I wanted to use the `text!` plugin, it won't work as plugin chaining is unsupported.

See https://github.com/jpillora/js-framework for what I've currently got, and also https://github.com/jpillora/prettyprinter for a use case.

Is there a clean way to solve this ? or to achieve multiple base URLs ?

Note: I have also looked into multiple require instances, though I don't think that would work as I'd like the the app to be able to access the framework's config.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Answered by James Burke on RequireJS Github Issue's page: [Issue #447: Multiple Base URLs · jrburke/requirejs](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/447).

Turns out to be quite simple if **data-main is the only entry point to your scripts(comments for more info)**, I solved my particular problem with the following:

My app's `index.html`:

```
<script src="http://framework.jpillora.com/js/lib/require.js" 
  data-main="http://framework.jpillora.com/js/framework" > </script>
```

has the requirejs entry point set to `framework.js`:

```
var framework = ... //set using script elements src attribute

require.config({

    baseUrl: 'js/',

    //Framework paths
    paths: {
      'framework': framework,
      'lib'      : framework + 'js/lib',
      'ext'      : framework + 'js/ext',
      'util'     : framework + 'js/util'
    },

    //Shortcuts
    map: {
      '*': {
        ...
      }
    },

    //Non-modularised libraries with deps
    shim: {
      ...
    }
});

require(['main']);
```

So instead of normally doing `index.html->main.js`, we're adding an extra step `index.html->framework.js->main.js`, which gives the app code knowledge of paths to the framework code.

For example, in the app http://prettyprint.jpillora.com/, once require has loaded `framework.js`, it will setup paths to `lib/...` which to http://framework.jpillora.com/ and set the `baseUrl` as `./js/` so once `main` is required, it will have the base url set to it's own domain and `lib` pointing to another domain.

Which results in `require(['lib/foo', 'view/bar']);` 
resolving to:

`http://framework.jpillora.com/js/lib/foo.js` and
`http://prettyprint.jpillora.com/js/view/bar.js`

As displayed here, the app is only a `main.js` everything else comes from the `framework`:

[image: chrome devtools loaded app]

So finally, whenever I load an app's `main.js` via with the above `framework.js`, I then have access to all of my commonly used libraries and utility classes. See app source.

Also note, with the `r.js` optimiser and a nice local file structure, one can also optimise the app into a single js file pulling only what's required from `framework`.

Comment: Hello.  Thank you for your answer for configuring RequireJs and DurandalJs to use paths to remote servers.  I've followed your approach and I can load the viewModel from the remote server.  However, when attempting to pull in the associated view, it seems Durandal's viewEngine cannot read the contents of the remote html file.  Any ideas?  I get an error message stating allElements is null (allElements is parameter passed to ensureSingleElement in viewEngine.js).

Comment: Keep in mind that the data-main attribute should only be used when this is the entry point to your dependency chain, and nothing else! The expected result might deviate based on environment, browsers and other race conditions. So in other words--the only right answer is just to define the paths to your modules.

Answer (score 10):

### The problem

I had a similar problem while trying to set up a testing environment. I had a file structure like this:

```
myApp/
    src/
        js/
            app.js
            data.js
            lib/underscore.js
    test/
        karma.conf.js
        test-main.js
        matchers.js
        spec/
            data.js
```

Here's where it gets tricky: my app scripts (`app.js` and `data.js`) assume a RequireJS configuration that resolves `data` to `src/js/data.js`, `lib/underscore` to `src/js/lib/underscore.js` etc, so I need that configuration in my test environment as well:

```
test/test-main.js
-----------------
require.config({
  // Karma serves files under /base, which is the basePath from your config file
  baseUrl: '/base/src/js',
  // ...
});
```

Now I can write my tests:

```
test/spec/data.js
-----------------
define(['data', '../../test/matchers'], function(dataModule) {
    describe('The data module', function() {
        it('should satisfy my custom matcher', function() {
            expect(dataModule).toSatisfyMyCustomMatcher();
        });
    });
});
```

With some custom matchers:

```
test/matchers.js
----------------
define([], function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        this.addMatchers({
            toSatisfyMyCustomMatcher: function() {
                return this.actual.isGood;
            },
        });
    });
});
```

However, that `'../../test/matchers'` part is horrendously ugly. The test specifications shouldn't be bothered with knowing file paths to other modules - that's RequireJS's job. Instead we want to use symbolic names.

### The solution

**The RequireJS [paths config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths) can also map directories.**

> The path that is used for a module name should not include an extension, since the path mapping could be for a directory.

So, the solution is a simple path config:

```
test/test-main.js
-----------------
require.config({
  baseUrl: '/base/src/js',
  paths: {
      test: '../../test',
  },
  // ...
});
```

Now I can refer to the `test` directory as if it were a child of the `baseUrl`:

```
test/spec/data.js
-----------------
define(['data', 'test/matchers'], function(dataModule) {
    // ...
});
```

Which in my case effectively comes out pretty much the same as if I could have multiple `baseUrl`s.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how we have handled routing and the context in [BoilerplateJS](http://boilerplatejs.org) which is a reference architecture for large-scale product development. We have used the library [crossroads.js](http://millermedeiros.github.com/crossroads.js/) to route modules and UI components. All there is to do is add the path/hash to the set of routes and it will be routed through the framework.

As an [example](https://github.com/ectechno/boilerplatejs/blob/master/src/modules/baseModule/module.js) all the paths of the UI components are added to the URL controller object.

As for accessing the framework configuration information throughout the application, configurations/settings can be attached to the global-context object which can be accessed inside the application.

Comment: Thanks for the response, though not the answer I was looking for. Turns out it's quite simple, see my answer.

Comment: Hello.  Thank you for your answer for configuring RequireJs and DurandalJs to use paths to remote servers.  I've followed your approach and I can load the viewModel from the remote server.  However, when attempting to pull in the associated view, it seems Durandal's viewEngine cannot read the contents of the remote html file.  Any ideas?  I get an error message stating allElements is null (allElements is parameter passed to ensureSingleElement in viewEngine.js).

Answer (score 0):

[requirejs multiversion](https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#multiversion)

TRY this

context: A name to give to a loading context. This allows require.js to load multiple versions of modules in a page, as long as each top-level require call specifies a unique context string. To use it correctly, see the Multiversion Support section.