# loading remote views with DurandalJs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, durandal, durandal-2.0

I'm learning DurandalJs and am trying to load a remote view from a different domain, however, requireJs keeps appending '.js' to the url for my html view resulting in a 404 error.  My goal is to setup a framework where I can reuse html snippets for different clients utilizing my app.  Here's the call to requirejs in the index.html file of my client app:

```
< script src="http://myframework.com/lib/require/require.js" 
  data-main="http://myframework.com/lib/framework"></script>
```

Notice I'm loading require.js from a totally different domain than my client app.  I'm setting the entry point to my app to framework.js which exists on myframework.com server.  Here's farmework.js:

```
    var framework = 'http://myframework.com/';

    require.config({

        baseUrl: 'app/',

        //Framework paths
        paths: 
        {
            'framework':        framework,
            'appBase':          framework + 'appBase',
            'lib'      :        framework + 'lib',      
            'durandal':         framework + 'lib/durandal',
            'jquery':           framework + 'lib/jquery/jquery-2.1.0.min',
            'knockout':         framework + 'lib/knockout/knockout-3.1.0'
             ...
        },
        urlArgs: 'v=5.1.0.5'
    });

    require(['main']);
```

After framework.js on my remote server runs, I've established a set of paths to resources in my framework.  I also set baseUrl to 'app' which resides on my client implementation.  So, the net result is I have a remote set of resources, and a local set of resources.  Please see this link: [SO source for how I accomplished this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12340092/418549)

Anyways, everything is working up to this point.  I'm able to load my remote resources.  I'm able to load 'main' on my client.  The problem happens when attempting to load a remote viewmodel and associated view.  I have a 'appBase' path where I want to have common viewModels and views to load across different implementations of my app.  I've set my route up as follows:

```
define(['plugins/router'], function (router)
{
    return {
        router: router,
        activate: function () {
            return router.map([
                { route: ['', 'home'], moduleId: 'appBase/viewmodels/home',title: 'Welcome'},
            ]).mapUnknownRoutes('hello/index', 'not-found')
              .activate();
        }
    };
});
```

Notice, I'm using 'appBase/viewmodels/home' for the moduleId.  appBase is one of the paths established in my framework that points to a location on my remote server.  requireJs is finding the path to the remote resource, but it's appending '.js' to the html file extension resulting in a 404 not found.  requireJs is producing this:

```
http://myframework.com/appBase/views/home.html.js
```

Any ideas on how to make DurandalJs load a viewmodule and its view on a remote server?  Why is .js getting appended to the Url for the html resource?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to remove the '.js' extension.  It has to do with cross-domain requests.  Very simple solution found here:

http://rockycode.com/blog/cross-domain-requirejs-text/